# Name of character in the Riftwar series

Tags: character-identification, riftwar-cycle

In the Riftwar series there was a Tsurani who was trapped on the side of Midkemia, and who had to adapt to life on the Midkemian side.

He became close to the pivotal characters, eventually helping to interpret Tsurani customs and such, and to help set up the peace talks I believe.

Not sure if Borric was still alive at that point, but the character was close at least to Borric's sons.

All I know is that his name vaguely resembled my name (I based my name on his), but I forgot what his original name is, and I can't find it back, all I find is the surrounding characters.

**EDIT**

I might have blended characters together, it has been 10 years since I read those books for the last time.

It isn't Kasumi but [jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia)'s answer did spark some more memory, it was more a normal soldier/warrior who was a prisoner of war at first, didn't speak Midkemian at all, and had to learn it.

Does anyone know who I mean, or do I have to read the books again to stumble upon him again?

Comment: Kasumi was sent as an emissary to set up the peace talks, but being trapped on Midkemia never happens until the fiasco at the peace talks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Charles or Tchakchakalla

> Tchakchakalla was a Tsurani of the Hunzan Clan, the son of a Force Leader. His great-grandfather was Warchief of his Clan. He had green eyes despite being swarthy, and short by Kingdom standards.

Early in the war Tchakchakalla's forces broke during fighting and he was reduced to a slave as punishment. He has later captured by Martin in the forests around Cydree. He then asked to either be offered the chance to serve or to be honourably killed.

He becomes close to Martin.

> Who is later revealed to be Borric's oldest son.